# Get data horizontally into html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to get data from the database and print it horizontally and vertically accordingly. I have a project table, there are can be multiple processes inside each project. And for each process, there is a number of assigned people. 
So what I did is got information about project first:

```
// 1.Get data
// data for final table
$result = [];
// map project no to its title
$projectNoToTitle = [];
$sql = '
    SELECT projectNo, code, title
    FROM `project`
    ORDER BY projectNo
';
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Then for each project I tried to get process and counted number of people in each user_type:

```
// for each process
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $sql2 = '
            SELECT projectNo, process, GROUP_CONCAT(col separator "+") as `count`
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT projectNo, process, concat(count(*),"(",user_type,")") as `col`
                FROM
                (
                    (
                         SELECT * FROM proc_leader t1 
                            LEFT JOIN
                            (
                                 SELECT username, user_type FROM user GROUP BY username
                            ) t2 ON t1.proc_leader = t2.username GROUP BY t1.proc_leader                    
                    )
                    UNION
                    (
                         SELECT * FROM proc_checker t1 
                            LEFT JOIN
                            (
                                SELECT username, user_type FROM user GROUP BY username
                            ) t2 ON t1.proc_checker = t2.username GROUP BY t1.proc_checker                          
                    )
                    UNION
                    (
                         SELECT * FROM proc_staff t1 
                            LEFT JOIN
                            (
                                SELECT username, user_type FROM user GROUP BY username
                            ) t2 ON t1.proc_staff = t2.username GROUP BY t1.proc_staff                                      
                    )  
                ) AS a GROUP BY projectNo, process, user_type
            ) t GROUP BY projectNo, process 
    ';
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    // for each project => process pair of user
    while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
        $projectN = $data['projectNo'];
        $code = $data['code'];      
        $title = $data['title'];
        $projectNo = $data2['projectNo'];
        $process = $data2['process'];
        $count = $data2['count'];

        $projectNoToTitle[$projectNo] = $process;

        if (!isset($result[$title])) {
            $result[$title] = [ 'code' => $code, 'projects' => []];
        }
        if (!isset($result[$title]['projects'][$projectNo])) {
            $result[$title]['projects'][$projectNo] = [];
        }
        if ($count) {
            $result[$title]['projects'][$projectNo][] = $count;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried to print my table:

```
<table>
<?php
// 2. Output table
// create table header
// it's columns should contain all processes
if ($result) 
{
    $header =
        '<th>Code</th>
        <th>Title</th>' .
        array_reduce(array_values($projectNoToTitle), function ($p, $n) {
            return $p . '<th>Process ' . htmlspecialchars($n) . '</th>';
        });

    // output body
    $body = '';
    foreach ($result as $title => $titleData) 
    {
        $row = '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($titleData['code']) . '</td>' . '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($title) . '</td>';
        foreach ($projectNoToTitle as $projectNo => $projectTitle) 
        {
            $r = isset($titleData['projects'][$projectNo])
                ? implode(', ', $titleData['projects'][$projectNo])
                : 'N/A';
            $row .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($r) . '</td>';
        }
        $body .= "<tr>$row</tr>";
    }
    echo "<thead>$header</thead><tbody>$body</tbody>";
}// \2. Output table
?>
</table>
```

And my expected output is:

```
| projectNo | code |   title   | Process ANM BGR | Process BLD COL |Process BGA CDP |
+-----------+------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
| 170001    |  pr1 |  Project1 |   1(FT)+1(CT)   |       1(AP)     |                |
| 170002    |  pr2 |  Project2 |                 |                 | 1(CT)          |
```

But instead I got:

```
| projectNo | code |   title   |        Process BGD COL    |        Process BGA CDP    |
+-----------+------+-----------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| 170001    |  pr1 |  Project1 |    1(CT)+1(FT), 1(AP)     |         1(CT)             |
| 170002    |  pr2 |  Project2 |    1(CT)+1(FT), 1(AP)     |         1(CT)             |
```

How can I arrange each process as column? Thank You

### EDIT

Table for `project` table:

```
project table:
| projectNo | code |   title  |
+-----------+------+----------+
| 170001    | pr1  | Project1 |
| 170002    | pr2  | Project2 |

process table:
| projectNo | process |
+-----------+---------+
| 170001    | ANM BGR |
| 170001    | BGD COL |
| 170002    | BGA CDP |

username table:
| uid | username   | user_type|
+-----+------------+----------+
| 1   | AARONJAMES | CT       |
| 2   | ADELINE    | AP       |
| 3   | AARONKOH   | CT       |
| 4   | AHMAD      | FT       |

proc_leader table:
| projectNo | process | proc_leader|
+-----------+---------+------------+
| 170001    | ANM BGR | AARONJAMES |
| 170001    | BGD COL | ADELINE    |
| 170002    | BGA CDP | AARONKOH   |

proc_checker table:
| projectNo | process | proc_checker |
+-----------+---------+--------------+
| 170001    | ANM BGR |  AARONJAMES  |
| 170001    | BGD COL |  AARONJAMES  |
| 170002    | BGA CDP |  AARONKOH    |

proc_staff table:
| projectNo | process | proc_staff |
+-----------+---------+------------+
| 170001    | ANM BGR |    AHMAD   |
```

### EDIT 2

What I got after updated answer is:

[image] So as you can see processes are repeated. But I need it to be under 1 column.
Like that:

```
| projectNo | code |   title   | Process ANM BGR | Process BLD COL |Process BGA CDP |
+-----------+------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
| 170001    |  pr1 |  Project1 |   1(FT)+1(CT)   |       1(AP)     |                |
| 170002    |  pr2 |  Project2 |     2(CT)       |                 | 1(CT)          |
```

Comment: Can you provide the structures of these relevant tables? Like on this [one](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142975/efficient-way-on-updating-multiple-tags-or-categories)

Comment: Ok thanks, just got time. Check my answer.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer. If it's still doesn't work, can you provide the new values you've just added? Thanks

Comment: Please help me to understand why you need to have left join on user table from different proc..... tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see is that you're doing the while loop inside a while loop when fetching data from different tables which I think it's hard to trace and merge them at the same time in this case. 
So I suggest, first get all data from your projects table and do your while.

e.g.

```
/** start for getting projects **/
$query = 'SELECT projectNo, code, title
          FROM `project`
          ORDER BY projectNo';

$res = $con->query($query);
$projects = [];
while ($data = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $projects[] = $data;
}
/** end for getting projects **/
```

Then do another query for getting data from different table and do your while loop. 
So once you get all the data you needed, you can easily merge them when you're doing your tables on html.

Check my working code:

```
/** start for getting projects **/
$query = 'SELECT projectNo, code, title
          FROM `project`
          ORDER BY projectNo';

$res = $con->query($query);
$projects = [];
while ($data = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $projects[] = $data;
}
/** end for getting projects **/


$titles = array();
$query = 'SELECT projectNo, process, GROUP_CONCAT(col separator "+") as `count`
          FROM 
          (
            SELECT projectNo, process, concat(count(*),"(",user_type,")") as `col`
            FROM
            (
                (
                     SELECT * FROM proc_leader t1 
                        LEFT JOIN
                        (
                             SELECT username, user_type FROM user GROUP BY username
                        ) t2 ON t1.proc_leader = t2.username GROUP BY t1.proc_leader                    
                )
                UNION
                (
                     SELECT * FROM proc_checker t1 
                        LEFT JOIN
                        (
                            SELECT username, user_type FROM user GROUP BY username
                        ) t2 ON t1.proc_checker = t2.username GROUP BY t1.proc_checker                          
                )
                UNION
                (
                     SELECT * FROM proc_staff t1 
                        LEFT JOIN
                        (
                            SELECT username, user_type FROM user GROUP BY username
                        ) t2 ON t1.proc_staff = t2.username GROUP BY t1.proc_staff                                      
                )  
            ) AS a GROUP BY projectNo, process, user_type 
          ) AS t GROUP BY projectNo, process';

$res = $con->query($query);
/** process the data first and store to variables and arrays **/
while ($data = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $projectNo = $data['projectNo'];
    $processName = $data['process'];
    $titles[] = $processName;
    $count = $data['count'];

    if (!isset($allProcess[$projectNo])) 
        $allProcess[$projectNo] = [];

    if ($count) 
        $allProcess[$projectNo][$processName] = $count;
}
?>

<style>
  table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
</style>
<table>
<?php
/** now do the printing of data **/
if ($allProcess)  {
    $header =
        '<th>ProjectNo</th>
         <th>Code</th>
         <th>Title</th>' .
        array_reduce(array_values($titles), function ($p, $n) {
            return $p . '<th>Process ' . htmlspecialchars($n) . '</th>';
        });

    $body = '';
    /** loop through projects first instead **/
    foreach ($projects as $p) {
        $body .= '<tr>';
        $body .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($p['projectNo']) . '</td>' . '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($p['code']) . '</td>' . '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($p['title']) . '</td>';

        /** loop through titles or all process **/
        foreach ($titles as $t) {
            $row = $allProcess[$p['projectNo']]; // e.g. Array ( [process] => Array ( [170001]...
            $r = isset($row) && isset($row[$t]) ? $row[$t] : 'N/A';
            $body .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($r) . '</td>';
        }
        $body .= '</tr>';
    }


    echo "<thead>$header</thead><tbody>$body</tbody>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Though there are still things that can be improved on that code above, this should give you a jump start.

**UPDATE**

Regarding getting the same two columns, you can add `$titles = array_unique($titles);` to get rid of the duplicate columns. You put that after the `while ($data = $res->fetch_assoc()) {` block.

```
/** process the data first and store to variables and arrays **/
$rows = [];
while ($data = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $data;
    $projectNo = $data['projectNo'];
    $processName = $data['process'];
    $titles[] = $processName;
    $count = $data['count'];

    if (!isset($allProcess[$projectNo])) 
        $allProcess[$projectNo] = [];

    if ($count) 
        $allProcess[$projectNo][$processName] = $count;
}

$titles = array_unique($titles); // the fix
```

Comment: It seems to work but after I add same process to two different projects I got two same columns. Please check my edit I added image. Thank you

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy Cool! Glad to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
    $projectN = $data['projectNo'];
    $code = $data['code'];      
    $title = $data['title'];
    $projectNo = $data2['projectNo'];
    $process = $data2['process'];
    $count = $data2['count'];

    // Here instead of overwriting, save process names in an array
    if (!isset($projectNoToTitle[$projectNo])) {
        $projectNoToTitle[$projectNo] = [];
    }
    $projectNoToTitle[$projectNo][] = $process;

    if (!isset($result[$title])) {
        $result[$title] = [ 'code' => $code, 'projects' => []];
    }
    if (!isset($result[$title]['projects'][$projectNo])) {
        $result[$title]['projects'][$projectNo] = [];
    }
    if ($count) {
        $result[$title]['projects'][$projectNo][] = $count;
    }
}
```

Then in the formatting code you need to change a couple of things:

```
$header =
    '<th>Code</th>
    <th>Title</th>' .
    array_reduce(array_values($projectNoToTitle), function ($p, $n) {
        // now $n is an array so implode it
        $header = '';
        foreach ($n as $p) {
            $header .= '<th>Process ' . htmlspecialchars($n)) . '</th>'
        }
        return $p . $header;
    });

// output body
$body = '';
foreach ($result as $title => $titleData) 
{
    $row = '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($titleData['code']) . '</td>' . '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($title) . '</td>';
    foreach ($projectNoToTitle as $projectNo => $projectTitle) 
    {
        $r = isset($titleData['projects'][$projectNo])
            // again, this is a brutal hack, you may rewrite part of
            // the code to do the same thing if you like.
            ? implode('</td><td>', $titleData['projects'][$projectNo])
            : 'N/A';
        $row .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($r) . '</td>';
    }
    $body .= "<tr>$row</tr>";
}
echo "<thead>$header</thead><tbody>$body</tbody>";
```

Note that this won't work if every project doesn't have the same processes, but maybe you get the point. Your question wasn't clear anyways, since you do not provide a sample table with more that one process in it, so I cannot know what exactely your are trying to do.

Anyways the problem is that you are overwriting the process name every time. Hope it helps!

Comment: Please refer to updated question, maybe it will give you more information